# WFFM not saving data

Tags: xdb, wffm

Sitecore 8.2 update 3. Just installed WFFM 8.2 update 3. Local (to CM) MongoDB for analytics (if that matters?)

I created a template for an item to save the results of a form submission and made "Create Item" as the only save action for the form. Mapped the form fields to the template fields and set a destination. The template consists of fields from itself as well as fields from base templates.

When installing WFFM, I did run the WFMM_Analytics.sql file on the reporting database (not doing this seems to be a common mistake). I made sure the new tables were created.

I made sure "Client Action" is checked for the save action. (tried unchecked as well).

I added read/write/create permissions for "default/anonymous" to the folder where the items are to be created and made sure descendants was also checked.

***Scroll down for update to this post with new errors***
When submitting the form on CM, I get an error on the page:

> We experienced a technical difficulty while processing your request. Your data may not have been correctly saved.

The message in the log is

> 1536 12:45:05 ERROR Exception when storing an aggregation result into reporting database. Item will be postponed and retried later.
>   Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   Message: Invalid object name 'FormFieldValues'.

When submitting on CD, it gives me a success message but saves nothing. In the log I see this:

> 5480 15:54:12 WARN  '{92F54CF7-F295-45A7-BBEC-E09F10126A19}' is not valid datasource.
>   5480 15:54:12 WARN  '{96C90A1F-8464-4E69-850C-5515915B990A}' is not valid datasource.
>   5480 15:54:12 WARN  '{4C9DF4E6-DD1F-4F3C-A86B-55807D6E1926}' is not valid datasource.

I have published the entire site.

### Update

I learned how to change my wffm data from the analytics database (mongoDB default) to SQL using this article: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-power-sitecore-wffm-through-sql-rohit-chopra/

Now when I submit the form from the CM, I get the following error in the log:

> ManagedPoolThread #9 09:31:10 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: master
>   4344 09:31:10 WARN  [WFFM] The '/sitecore/content/Home/Form Submissions/Contact Us' item has not been found.
>   Exception: Sitecore.Exceptions.RequiredObjectIsNullException
>   Message: The '/sitecore/content/Home/Form Submissions/Contact Us' item has not been found.
>   Source: Sitecore.Forms.Custom
>      at Sitecore.Form.Submit.CreateItem.CreateItemByFields(ID formid, AdaptedResultList fields)
>      at Sitecore.Form.Submit.CreateItem.Execute(ID formId, AdaptedResultList adaptedFields, ActionCallContext actionCallContext, Object[] data)
>      at Sitecore.Forms.Core.Dependencies.DefaultImplActionExecutor.ExecuteSaving(ID formID, ControlResult[] fields, IActionDefinition[] actionDefinitions, Boolean simpleAdapt, ID sessionID)

The item mentioned in lines 2 and 4 above do exist in the master and web databases. it is a folder meant to store form submission items from this form.

Comment: What do you your formsDataProvider set to ? are you storing into SQL or Mongo?

Comment: MongoDB, but I wanted it to be SQL. This is the first I read about it (wasn't in the installation guide).  I searched on it and found https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-power-sitecore-wffm-through-sql-rohit-chopra/ which seems to have helped. Now I have a different error: Updating the original post.

Comment: can you change that folder path so it does not have spaces? also make sure the folder exists in all language versions if you have any

Comment: No effect. It is working now that I have altered the template. What I neglected to mention is that the template I was using for the created item had two base templates. When I removed these and incorporated their fields directly into the template, it started working... I don't understand why this would correct the problem, but it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the original problem, I was able to update my installation to use SQL instead of MongoDB (default) for WFFM. After that, the second issue I ran into was resolved by removing base templates and incorporating all fields into a single template.

I don't know why this would work, so if anyone can give better details, I would mark their response as the answer.